# I don't understand runnable, it is so confusing

Tags: android, runnable

I have got this code that connect to a server and send message, it works perfectly, I just don't get the idea of runnable.
Is the code within the run(){ } is executed in a loop?
I tried puttin a log.e inside, and it only prints once, so how does it actually work?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e("in try","run");
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How come the app still able to connect to the server? If the server is down and I run the app, I am assuming that the run didn't connect to the server, so then I start the server after the app and then click send, it still manages to connect and send the text to the server, how is that?

Comment: See my comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the code within the run(){ } is executed in a loop?

- No, the code that you provided at least will not run in a loop.

**Note:** You can use other ways to call it in a loop like handler can post it again to the handler with the call to - `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);` every `1000 ms`.

### public interface Runnable -

*Represents a command that can be executed. Often used to run code in a different Thread.*

Public Methods:

> **public abstract void run ()**
>
> Starts executing the active part of the class' code. This method is
>   called when a thread is started that has been created with a class
>   which implements Runnable.

**Basics of Runnable -**

Using `Runnable` Interface, you can run the class several times.

Example -

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

         Log.e("in try","run");
         //Some code
    }
  }

//Multiple threads share the same object.
ClientThread  rc = new ClientThread ();
Thread t1 = new Thread(rc);
t1.start();
Thread.sleep(1000); // Waiting for 1 second before starting next thread
Thread t2 = new Thread(rc);
t2.start();
Thread.sleep(1000); // Waiting for 1 second before starting next thread
Thread t3 = new Thread(rc);
t3.start();
```

Reference: [Runnable in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html).

Comment: `how come the app still able to connect to the server even after restart?` - Are you sure it was started once previously on the very first call ? Are you sure there is no *other* call to start this Runnable class anywhere else in the code ?

Comment: How about restarting my router and get new IP addresses?

Comment: No problem. As far as you are providing IP address as the parameter in the method you can always connect with the correct IP that you pass into it. Make sure to run the app after doing restart.

Comment: Just tried with the new IP, it is not sending the message if I start the server after the app, so it means it didn't connect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question - no, `run()` method in `Runnable` is not executed in a loop. It is executed only once.

It just represents something that can be done in future, most often in a different `Thread`.

Comment: Appologise, deleted them all and now my question is a comment under my main post above

Answer (score 0):

The function of `Runnable` has been explained in the answers above. To your comments on these answers:

Did you debug, if the socket really opens a connection and you see the data on the server input? Does it return an OutputStreamWriter object? If the server is down you shouldn't be able to send anything. However that doesn't imply the android code to fail. The output could be set up and writing stuff to its buffer/stream, but it's never put out.